# How to solve Vuejs composition API's Ref() type Error?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typeerror, vue-composition-api

I am using vue composition API  and using a ref for an array of objects which each object has a value property, it seems that the typescript confusing ref's value with the property value inside of each array:

[image]

As you see in the above picture, typescript telling us the type of arr is an array of object which contains name and value, but when i used ref, it detects the wrong type. even if i used as conversion like below the problem wont solve:

```
const arr2 = ref(arr as { name: string; value: number }[]);
```

But when i change the value property to value2 or something else, it will work:
[image]

**update**:

here is another problem which i have faced today:

[image]

I'm wondering how should i solve this type error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a shame that you've used an image to show your code, because I have to retype it all again.

Yes, it seems clear that using 'value' as a key in your object confuses Typescript.
You can get round it by declaring an **interface**, which you then also use to declare **arr2**

```
    interface thing {
        name: string,
        value: number
    };

    const arr: thing[] = [
        {name: "x1", value: 1},
        {name: "x2", value: 2}
    ];

    const arr2: Ref<thing[]> = ref(arr);

    arr2.value.forEach(item => console.log(item.name + ':' + item.value));
```

However the best way to get round it is not to use 'value' as a key in your objects obviously, because it's likely a reserved word in Javascript and/or Typescript.

Comment: after upgrading composition-api from 0.5.0 to 0.6.7 ,we should use `Ref<thing[]>` at the right hand side, e.g:     `const arr2 = ref(arr) as Ref<thing[]>;`

https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/432#issuecomment-655248923

Comment: `const items = ref({ heart: [], lungs: [],});` how to define this properly?